# Why doesn't the event get activated, even thought I have a listener and @EvenHandler?

Tags: java, events, bukkit

So I am working on a plugin, but none of my events get activated.

As an example, I have this event:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerDeath(PlayerDeathEvent event){
  Bukkit.getBanList(BanList.Type.NAME).addBan(event.getEntity().getName(), "Du bist hiermit aus Combat ausgeschieden!", null, "");
}
```

Its in a class, which is implemented as Listener.
And thats in my class which extends JavaPlugin (EditTeams is the listener):

```
EditTeams events = new EditTeams();
public void onEnable(){
    Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(events, this);
}
```

I looked around a lot, but couldn't find the problem.

Comment: Can you append your `latest.log` and maybe add some `System.out.println("")`'s to the `onEnable()` and your listener so we can see what the server does in the background?

Answer (score 0):

try and use -

```
Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new EditTeams(), this);
```

Also, I am pretty sure you need to actually kick the user, then ban them -> `e.getPlayer().kick("Reason");` then add them to the ban list.

Comment: from the official docs from spigot 1.14 there is no difference from `Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager()` to `Bukkit.getPluginManager()`
https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Bukkit.html#getPluginManager--
https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Server.html#getPluginManager--

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the `@Override` Annotation to your `onEnable()` method. If that wont work simply test which methods get called

```
EditTeams events = new EditTeams();
public void onEnable(){
    System.out.println("OnEnable() triggered");
    Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(events, this);
}

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerDeath(PlayerDeathEvent event){
  System.out.println("PlayerDeathEvent Triggered.");
  Bukkit.getBanList(BanList.Type.NAME).addBan(event.getEntity().getName(), "Du bist hiermit aus Combat ausgeschieden!", null, "");
}
```

Do you have any Exception/Stacktraces thrown in your Sysout?